# What is the default cache policy of cloudfront (when regular lambda running calling by api gateway )

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

What is the default cache policy of "cloudfront" (when regular lambda running calling by api gateway )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you configure for the TTL and whether you configure caching.  Check out the "Does Amazon API Gateway provide API result caching" FAQ under Throttling and Caching:
https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/

> You can add caching to API calls by provisioning an API Gateway cache
> and specifying its size in gigabytes. The cache is provisioned for a
> specific stage of your APIs. This improves performance and reduces the
> traffic sent to your back end. Cache settings allow you to control the
> way the cache key is built and the time-to-live (TTL) of the data
> stored for each method. API Gateway also exposes management APIs that
> help you invalidate the cache for each stage. Caching is available for
> REST APIs in API Gateway.

If you enable this, then per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html

> The default TTL value for API caching is 300 seconds.

If you configure an [Edge-optimized API endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-basic-concept.html#apigateway-definition-edge-optimized-api-endpoint) then you can [configure your own CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/) and manage that in the [CloudFront settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior).  If you do that, [CloudFront documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) states that

> By default, each file automatically expires after 24 hours

Also see [API Gateway Caching vs CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490508/api-gateway-caching-vs-cloudfront)

Comment: tnx, the point is that I don't use "Enable API cache" and I want to know the default TTL and catch settings of Lamda that use API Gateway (by default )